# html make <td> height proportional to the width

Tags: css, html, drag-and-drop, html-table

I would like to generate a table with relative sizes. For example, I would like an empty table with 14 columns and 1 row. The row height should be as 0.75 of the width of one cell. In this case, with 14 columns, one cell would be around 7% width.

The purpose that I'm using empty table is that: I'm using the drag and drop function provided by html5. I would like to drag something and drop into the different cells of the empty table.

Currently, I found ways to using padding to have the desired height when it is empty. However, the problem with padding is once you drag something into the empty cell, it will still has the empty padding area.

Anybody have suggestions what should I do?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can place a `DIV` in your cells, you can use the following CSS to ensure that each cell's height is 75% of its width:

```
td {
  position: relative;
}

td > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

td:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 75%;
}
```

This is based on the fact that padding is always a function of an element's width, not its height.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vk6csmfq/)

Comment: Thanks, Rick. But this is exactly what I have used. And the padding empty space is there after I dropped something into the cell.

Comment: Have you used this with the absolute positioning and `:before` selectors?  If so, could you post an example?

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/vk6csmfq/1/ and drag the image into a cell.  Note that it doesn't expand.  Is this your goal?

Comment: It doesn't expand, but it is not in the cell as well. I want to picture to be in the cell and the pic should resize to the size of the cell automatically, which I've already achieved. But I don't want the cell to change.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "it is not in the cell"?  Here's a version where it expands to the size of the cell:  https://jsfiddle.net/vk6csmfq/2/

Comment: Wow! This works perfectly and is exactly what I want! Thanks a lot! I think the td>div is a very important thing to know.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run some javascript on drag. You could have a class on cells when empty that adds the padding and remove that class from the cell once something has been dragged into it. 
So, when generating your html make sure that each cell has an `empty` class on it. Then remove that class when dragging something into it. If the cell can be emptied, then you'd have to re-apply the class. All these operations can be done during a drag. To determine whether a cell is empty just see if it has the `empty` class on it.

Comment: Thanks, but could you make it more clear? How to know the cell is empty?

Comment: No need to know if it's empty just remove the class when something has been dragged into it. But, You would know by checking whether the ``empty`` class exists on the cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to size your table with viewport sizing, I think this is achievable.

For example if your table is sized at 100vw (full screen width) and you have ~7% width columns (or ~7vw), then you could set the height of the table cell to be calc(0.75 * ~7vw).

```
table {
    width: 100vw;
}
tr {
    height: calc(0.75 * 7.1428vw);
}
td {
    width: 7.1428% /* or 7.1428vw */
}
```

You could add calculations to the table as well (doesn't have to be 100vw, just based off of the viewport).

Are you able to use viewport sizing for the table?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to use viewport sizing.

Comment: Doesn't mean you can't learn! :) Check out this codepen as a starting point. You can see here that the height of the row is 75% of the width of the cells. http://codepen.io/smrubin/pen/dMVYOW