# Keep the height/width ratio of table

Tags: javascript, css

I have a simple table design, a square with 3x3 cells -think Rubik's cube. I want this table's width to always be 30% of the window and I don't want the height/width ratio change if the browser window is being resized. Also I want the inner 3x3 cells to be able to keep text and/or images without the symmetry being distorted. Is this possible with only css/javascript? I've tried sooooooooo many things but none has been working so far.

EDIT: I've added one of my many attempts to solve this below. The code works in Chrome when I try it in the broswer... but not here for some reason. However, it didn't solve my initial problem so I guess it's no problem.

```js
       function getTableWidth(){
        var element = document.getElementById("table");
        var intElemClientWidth = element.clientWidth;
        document.getElementById("table").style.height=intElemClientWidth;
}
```

```css
    .cell{ 
    height: 33%;
    width: 33%;
```

```html
<div onclick="getTableWidth()">Get 1:1 ratio</div>
    
<table id="table" width="30%" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell">1</td>
      <td class="cell">2</td>
      <td class="cell">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td class="cell"></td>
      <td class="cell"></td>
      <td class="cell"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell"></td>
      <td class="cell"></td>
      <td class="cell"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you mean. Let me provide a modified solution from here: [html make <td> height proportional to the width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36342702/html-make-td-height-proportional-to-the-width)

```css
table {
  width: 30%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

td > div {
  position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

td:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
      <tr>
        <td><div>1</div></td>
        <td><div>2</div></td>
        <td><div>3</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div>1</div></td>
        <td><div>2</div></td>
        <td><div>3</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div>1</div></td>
        <td><div>2</div></td>
        <td><div>3</div></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: But how does this make the height of the cube shaped table stay in relation to the width?

Comment: I provided a different solution above, from what I understand from your question, it works on chrome and firefox

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Very nice! :) I'm not really sure how it works but I will experiment with values in this to understand better. Thanks again!

Comment: Btw. This is my first post here and I see that my question has been "voted down" by two, does that mean that there is something in my question that wasn't good or clear?

Comment: I'm pretty new here as well but I think it has to do with not providing your code which would've showed what you've done or attempted even if it failed, but that's just my guess. On another note, if the answer I provided helps can you choose ot as the answer? That way people who come across this know there's something useful.

Answer (score -1):

Yep it's possible just with HTML and some styling, you can easily control the table's width using percentages (Yes they are responsive):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Basic HTML Table</h2>

<table style="width:30%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table

Comment: Mm, but this is not really my question. My question is that I want this Rubik's cube like table to have a 1:1 height to width ratio all the time -no matter browser window size. Also I want the width to always be at 30%...

Comment: The only way for this is to hard code a specific width and a specific height, either that or by using Javascript to get the page's width first, then setting the table's width and height to be 30% of that value.

Comment: Also the any element's height and width are limited to the font-size so if you're using a large font it may not always work.

Comment: Yeah, initially I though it to be a pretty simple task but... that's why I'm here now. :)